# How to use Auto compiler for less and sass in visual studio

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2015, sass, less

I am beginner in using less and sass

As it seems there is no way to link less or sass file directly to html page. so it needs compilation to Css

As I read in some articles I installed web compiler and also web essentials.But I don't know how to use them.

and still there is no auto compiler in my visual window.

here it said I should right Click on my sass or less file in solution:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c

but web compiler is not in my solution:

[image]

does any one know any step by step tutorial or guide?

Really thank you.

Comment: When you open the Web Essentials menu item at the top, is there a "Compile all SASS files" option? If not, it sounds like you don't have both extensions installed.

Comment: thank you for your care . @i7nvd  where do you mean of top? in visual? there is no web essential menu

Comment: Are you sure you actually installed it? Can you see web compiler in in Tools > Extensions and Updates -> Web Compiler? Web Essentials dropped SASS/LESS compiling, and only thing that you need now is a plugin called Web Compiler.

Comment: @kasperoo To be fair, I don't use 2015, but knew he separated out the functions. But my understanding was you needed both Web Essentials AND Web Compiler, where WC is a plugin/component of the WE suite.

Comment: No, you don't need both anymore - hence they splitted that. Just to prove a point I installed only web compiler plugin on my surface within vs2015 (I have no web essentials) and the compiler built sass without any problems.

Comment: @kasperoo  I checked the Extensions and Updates and web compiler was not in the list. I tried to install it again but when I run the .exe file it has the Error : this extension is Already installed to all applicable products. Do you have any idea how to solve it? thanks again for your care

Comment: Do you have more than one instance of Visual Studio?

Comment: it seems so. I checked add or remove list and there is two version of visual there .community 2015 with update 1 and ultimate 2013 with update 4 should I remove 2013 version right? @kasperoo

Comment: You might have installed extension for a particular version - can you open the other one and see if it's installed?

Comment: wooooooooow that was the exact problem. I've never care that I am using 2013 version. yes yes it is in 2015 version. really thank you really really . @kasperoo

Comment: Is it possible for you to answer this question then I could accept and close it @kasperoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your plugin is not installed at all. If you are sure that you installed the plugin in Visual Studio, double check how many other versions of VS you actually have - and check whether or not you have accidentally installed it in some other instance by accident